# Video lectures on type systems

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, education, types-and-programming-languages

For my job, I need to pick up a working understanding of the implementation of type systems (in particular, how to write typing rules based on a design document). I've been given a copy of *Types and Programming Languages* and that's great, but I'd really like to watch someone work through it.

In my school, the course that teaches this is called "Programming Languages," but searching for "video lectures programming languages" turns up lots of stuff about how to learn C++, which I'm not interested in. I couldn't find anything on MIT Open Courseware.

I'd really like video lectures that go through *TAPL*, but I'll settle for anything useful. Are there good resources out there?

Comment: Should this be a wiki?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: No; CW is dead in the water and has no clearly defined use case (anymore).

Comment: Crazy thought: have you [tried googling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=video%20lecture%20Types%20and%20Programming%20Languages)?

Comment: I suggest you spend more time searching, and don't give up so easily.  One simple search strategy is to pick 10 well-known universities, look at the list of courses they offer, look for one that is about programming languages and types, then check to see what textbook or lecture notes each one uses (e.g., by finding its web page), and see if they offer video lectures.  This should be straightforward, and will avoid the problems with Googling "video lectures programming languages".  You could also look on Coursera/Udacity.

Comment: @Raphael Yes -- all of the Oregon Summer School results are targeted at a significantly higher level. Then there's a page from a CMU course (no course material online). Then there's this question. I checked Coursera and didn't find anything. These IIT Madras lectures seem to be okay (I had passed over them because freevideolectures.com didn't sound like a credible source), but still, it's not like there's an abundance of good material jumping out on the 1st page of Google. It's not like I didn't look.

Comment: @DW I checked MIT because I know they have lecture videos. No dice (did find a class, but no lectures). I checked Coursera and I didn't find anything there either. On your recommendation, I looked at Udacity, which [has this](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs262), which seems to be about parsing and not typing. I don't know of any other universities off the top of my head that have video lectures -- I'm not interested in just syllabi, because I can get that from my own school. If I'm missing something obvious, please correct me.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: Too bad. With online content you know all the important buzzwords of, chances are, if Google does not know it (checking pages 2,3,4,... may be advisable) it does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you poke around the [Oregon Programming Languages Summer School](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer14/) web site you should find a lot of video lectures on the topic, given by the leaders in the area. For instance, see Robert Harper's "Type Theory Foundations" on the [curriculum](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer14/curriculum.html) page.

Comment: That's what I was going to say. Great answer. I had trouble at first getting the videos to work with Internet Explorer, so I changed to another one and it worked. I don't believe they are compressed so be ready to have you bandwidth abused.

Comment: Bob Harper is incompressible.

Comment: I found (and watched) some of Bob Harper's lecture from 2012, but they're at a significantly higher level than TAPL -- the 2012 page lists TAPL as a prereq.

Comment: Yeah, the lectures cover more than TaPL, but it's the only online lectures I've seen which cover what is in TaPL. This is your best bet if you really want video lectures, but whichever way you cut it, there's no substitute for working through the examples in TaPL.